# NPE When running Netbeans using the GTK LAF

Tags: java, properties, gtk, look-and-feel

Recently, I got a weird stack trace in the netbeans logs (I added it to the end of this post). I was able to track it down to the LAF. This error happens, when running Netbeans using the GTK LAF, but works fine in Metal, and using the native Windows LAF.

It seems, that the PropertyChangeSupport instance is NULL, so it throws an error when adding a Property change listener. Here's the abbreviated source of my custom component:

```
public class EnterprisePicker extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener, ListSelectionListener, UnitContainer {

    private static final Logger logger = IdeUiUtil.initLogger(EnterprisePicker.class.getName());
    protected InfoPanelStyle infoPanelStyle = InfoPanelStyle.FULL;
    private final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    public static final String PROP_INFOPANELSTYLE = "infoPanelStyle";

    /** Creates the new component */
    public EnterprisePicker() {
        // [... snip ...]
    }

    // [ ... snip ... ]

    /**
     * Add PropertyChangeListener.
     *
     * @param listener
     */
    @Override
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    // [ ... snip ... ]

}
```

Obviously I could simply protect these calls using `if (propertyChangeSupport == null)`... But would that not break properties later on in the application? Assuming that no listener will ever be attached as the instance is `null`...?

#### Stack Trace

```
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.form.BeanSupport]: Cannot create default instance of: org.statec.ide.ui.components.EnterprisePicker
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.statec.ide.ui.components.EnterprisePicker.addPropertyChangeListener(EnterprisePicker.java:654)
        at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.installListeners(SynthPanelUI.java:49)
        at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.installUI(SynthPanelUI.java:38)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:662)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(JPanel.java:136)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:109)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:69)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:92)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:100)
        at org.statec.ide.ui.components.EnterprisePicker.<init>(EnterprisePicker.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.CreationFactory.createDefaultInstance(CreationFactory.java:168)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.form.BeanSupport.createBeanInstance(BeanSupport.java:83)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.BeanSupport.getDefaultInstance(BeanSupport.java:109)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:769)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:1007)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:527)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:299)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor$3.run(FormEditor.java:337)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:293)
        at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1361)
        at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:320)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:276)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormData(FormEditor.java:334)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormDesigner(FormEditor.java:232)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormDesigner.finishComponentShowing(FormDesigner.java:1932)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormDesigner.access$1100(FormDesigner.java:107)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormDesigner$PreLoadTask$1.run(FormDesigner.java:1897)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
        at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:148)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
INFO
org.openide.ErrorManager$AnnException: msg
        at org.openide.ErrorManager$AnnException.findOrCreate(ErrorManager.java:866)
        at org.openide.ErrorManager$DelegatingErrorManager.annotate(ErrorManager.java:653)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.annotateException(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:237)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.annotateException(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:247)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:865)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:1007)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:527)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:299)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor$3.run(FormEditor.java:337)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:293)
        at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1361)
        at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:320)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:276)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormData(FormEditor.java:334)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormDesigner(FormEditor.java:232)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormDesigner.finishComponentShowing(FormDesigner.java:1932)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormDesigner.access$1100(FormDesigner.java:107)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormDesigner$PreLoadTask$1.run(FormDesigner.java:1897)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
        at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:148)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
msg
Caused: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.statec.ide.ui.components.EnterprisePicker.addPropertyChangeListener(EnterprisePicker.java:654)
        at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.installListeners(SynthPanelUI.java:49)
        at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.installUI(SynthPanelUI.java:38)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:662)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(JPanel.java:136)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:109)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:69)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:92)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:100)
        at org.statec.ide.ui.components.EnterprisePicker.<init>(EnterprisePicker.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.CreationFactory.createDefaultInstance(CreationFactory.java:168)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.RADComponent.createBeanInstance(RADComponent.java:252)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.RADComponent.initInstance(RADComponent.java:191)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:851)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:1007)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:527)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:299)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor$3.run(FormEditor.java:337)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:293)
        at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1361)
        at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:320)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:276)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormData(FormEditor.java:334)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormDesigner(FormEditor.java:232)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormDesigner.finishComponentShowing(FormDesigner.java:1932)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormDesigner.access$1100(FormDesigner.java:107)
        at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormDesigner$PreLoadTask$1.run(FormDesigner.java:1897)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
        at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:148)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Error in loading component: [JDialog]->enterprisePicker1
Cannot create instance of org.statec.ide.ui.components.EnterprisePicker.
The component cannot be loaded.
```

And for reference:

```
malbert@dredg:~/.netbeans/7.0/var/log$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

malbert@dredg:~/.netbeans/7.0/var/log$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=natty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.04"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but the problem could be that during initialization of some super class `addPropertyChangeListener(...)` is called (`javax.swing.JPanel.<init>` might be the culprit), thus this call happens before `propertyChangeSupport` is initialized.

The initialization sequence of instance fields would be:

- Object
- Component
- Container
- JComponent
- JPanel
- EnterprisePicker

If during initialization of `JPanel` the `addPropertyChangeListener(...)` method is called, it would actually be the overridden version of `EnterprisePicker`, but `EnterprisePicker`'s fields would not have been initialized yet.

To fix this you'd check for `null` in that method and initialize as needed (or call `super.addPropertyChangeListener(...)`. Is there any need to have your own implementation (to add your own `PropertyChangeSupport`)?

Comment: Yes. I implemented my own PCS... I'll give it a try to protect with `if ... == null` then... But could that not break the PCS in cases the PCS accidentally *is* `NULL`?

Comment: @exhuma you might try and initialize it when it is null instead of waiting for the initializer block to run (note that it can't be final then). Alternatively, you could just keep the final keyword and redirect to `super.addPropertyChangeListener(...)` while the PCS is null and in the constructor you'd then add the listeners from super to your PCS as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think I prefer the first solution (initialising the PCS in case it's NULL).

Comment: Okay... after another read of your comment I decided to use the redirection to `super` afterall. However,... this still does not make it clear to me why this only happens in GTK...?

Comment: @exhume I assume that GTK tries to add some listeners that the other LAF implementations don't.